Need to add built in alert into the exit logic
I'm trying to make it so that the alerts are generated by function calls only and I was able to get entries to work using the alert(" ") function, but I can't get it to work properly with the exit logic. My exit logic contains a trailing stop and a fixed stop loss. If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.
strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", trail_points=(close \* trailingStopPercentage / 100), trail_offset=(close \* trailingStopPercentage / 100), stop=(close - fixedTickStopLoss \* syminfo.mintick))
strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Short", trail_points=(close \* trailingStopPercentage / 100), trail_offset=(close \* trailingStopPercentage / 100), stop=(close + fixedTickStopLoss \* syminfo.mintick))

I tried to add the alert(" ") directly into the exit logic using what is below, but since its a trailing stop it doesn't work.
if (strategy.position_size \> 0)
strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", trail_points=(close \* trailingStopPercentage / 100), trail_offset=(close \* trailingStopPercentage / 100), stop=(close - fixedTickStopLoss \* syminfo.mintick))
alert("Exit Short") // Opposite alert for exiting long

